# React-native: how to save webview state on minimize

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use `WebView` in my react-native app (Android).
When i press `home` button and when start app again `webview` doesn't save his state.

I read some articles and my code now is:

```js
var freetime = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      url: DEFAULT_URL,
      backButtonEnabled: false,
      forwardButtonEnabled: false,
      loading: true,
      scalesPageToFit: true,
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return(
      <WebView
      url={this.state.url}
      onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavStateChanged}/>
    );
  },

  onNavStateChanged: function(navState) {
    console.log("Url: " + navState.url);
    console.log("Source: " + navState.source);

    this.setState({
      url: navState.url,
      status: navState.title,
      scalesPageToFit: true
    });
  }
});
```

But it didn't work too.

Comment: component states are not permament properties if you need to get same value whenever app is launched you can use asyncstorage.In case of keeping values duringa lifecycle of application(start to close) you can use mobx or redux.